# Does anyone know how to make nhibernate map char(n) columns to a string without adding trailing whitespace?

Tags: nhibernate

Say if you have a char(5) column in the db and you have "ABC" in there, if you map this column to a string property you will find nhibernate will map it as "ABC__" where the underscores represent whitespace of some sort (I haven't checked what ascii code it is)

For a long time now we just solved this problem by changing the column to varchar and trimming all the entries in the DB. It would be better if there was a solution that let us keep the columns as char(n) (if only to save us some work)

I guess I could try trimming on get and padding on set, but that doesn't strike me as the greatest solution.

So, is there some nice way to configure nhibernate to read a char(n) column into a string without it reading in extra whitespace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. You can use a formula property on a field tag to set the value to RTrim(myCharField) but then it won't be bound. That is to say, any changes you make to the field won't be saved to the database.

I don't really see why this is a problem though. If you're designing your application with a data layer it should be simple enough to add a trim call to  the getter method of the entity's properties before returning shouldn't it?

Comment: the trim to the get isn't quite enough, sometimes if you read the property into some user editable field like a datagridview, the trimmed values make their way back into set and if the session gets flushed useless update statements get created

Comment: I was just thinking I could just make sure to pad all values coming into the set back to what it is in the first place to prevent that, though. I was just hoping that there was some magical way to configure things that would stop me from having to do this every time.

Comment: "if the session gets flushed useless update statements get created" Unless there's something unusual about your application where entities are routinely saved automatically (as opposed to some button click by the user) the number of useless updates is going to be fairly insignificant. The user would have to open up the entity, make no changes and click save. I don't believe that happens very often.

Comment: Sometimes we've made grids with quite a lot of entries on them. One had a few thousand items in there. All the useless update statements caused quite a delay... I guess we can design the screens around this problem.. but I'd rather just not have those useless update statements

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah it sounds like all you're stuck with is stuff you don't really want to do. Since all options are somewhat painful I would at least recommend you choose the one that cleans up your database (switch char fields to varchar)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Spencer! I guess some problems have no elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database you are using, but we use iSeries DB2, and we have the same issue with trailing whitespaces. We created a custom user type to "trim" the values from these columns: [TrimmedUser.cs gist](https://gist.github.com/4225905)

This works because iSeries DB2 doesn't consider trailing whitespace when doing a string comparison (i.e., 'MYSTRING' equals 'MYSTRING   '). If this isn't true for your particular database, you could probably handle that in the "NullSafeSet" method, by right padding with the whitespace character used by your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version of Andy's gist:

```
public class TrimmedString : NHibernateFactoryType<string>
{
    public override SqlType[] SqlTypes => new[] { new SqlType(DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength) };

    public override object NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        var str = (string)NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0], session);
        return str?.Trim();
    }

    public override void NullSafeSet(DbCommand cmd, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        value = ((string)value)?.Trim();  //Not really necessary
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index, session);
    }
}
```